# Django: where is settings.py looking for imports, and why?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app with a common directory structure:

```
project
---manage.py
---app
   ---__init__.py
   ---settings.py
   ---settings_secret.py
   ---a bunch of other files for the app itself
```

That settings_secret.py file contains variables from secrets.py which I do not want to send to github.  For some reason, I cannot seem to import it into settings.py. First 5 lines of settings.py:

```
# Django settings for project. 
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
import os
from settings_secret import *
```

Which fails with the partial stacktrace:

```
File "/foo/bar/project/app/settings.py", line 5, in <module> from settings_secret import *
ImportError: No module named 'settings_secret'
```

To debug, I created a test file inside /project/ like so:

```
from settings_secret import *
print(VARIABLE_FROM_SETTINGS_SECRET)
```

Which worked like a charm. So clearly, settings.py isn't looking in the right place for settings_secret. So where is it looking?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file under `app`? You should also do `from .settings_secret import *` in `settings.py`.

Comment: I do have an `__init__.py`, just forgot to include in question. Edited in.  And yes, I tried `.settings_secret import *` and it worked - but why? Why does it work and why didn't it work with no dot, like it does in my test file?

Comment: I think you should rather set your imports through environment variables, and not a "secret file". http://12factor.net/config

Comment: By the ways, if you want to check where python is looking for packages, check `sys.path` through poor man's debugger: `print sys.path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `settings.py`, you should do: `from .settings_secret import *`

It works with the `.` because the proper syntax is supposed to be:

`from app.settings_secret import *`

Removing the `app` is shorthand coding, but  the same principle applies. You need to tell Django to look for the directory (`app`), and then you are specifying which file in that directory to look for.

If you just did, `from settings_secret import *`, you are telling Django to look for the directory `settings_secret`, which doesn't exist.

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. As asked, this is obviously the correct answer, so I'm accepting. geekazoid made a good point in the comments above, though, and others should consider using environment variables instead of a local settings file when possible.